# Should I use SELECT or the duplicate unique key error to check if user and/or email exist?

Tags: postgresql, validation, constraints

Talking to some coworkers they said that we do not should check if the unique key already exists with a SELECT. The check must be done with constraints error returned by the database.

I have the following scenario:

1. I need to return a message to the user informing if username OR
   email is already registered(username and email is unique key).
2. I need to generate the password hash to insert a new user.

If I validate username and email(both are unique keys) based on the error of constraint violation returned by the database I can not know if it is the username OR the email that already exist registered.

If I simply INSERT the user into the database before checking the existence of the username and email, and one or the other already exist, I would be wasting unnecessary processing time for having generated the password hash.

What would be the best approach in this case? Considering data integrity if using a SELECT before INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

You could proceed like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
VALUES ('newuser', 'newemail', NULL)
ON CONFLICT (username) DO NOTHING
RETURNING id;
```

If you got an empty result, there was a collision with an existing user name.

If you get a constraint violation, there was a collision with an existing e-mail address.

If you get an `id`, back, set the password:

```
UPDATE users
SET password = 'newpassword'
WHERE id = v_id;
```

If the table has a `fillfactor` of less than 100, and there is no index on `password` (which there shouldn't be), this could be an efficient HOT update.

But I would measure if hash creation is more expensive than an extra database round trip...